# Solution Explorer in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio-2022, explorer, solution

I just installed Visual Studio 2022 professional, installation went perfectly without failures. However, when I try to create any project I get solution explorer like this ('Webapplication1' (0 project) ) and it doesn't show the normal hierarchy with controller and startup file, etc. How to fix this issue?

It looks as follows:

[image]

[image]

I tried to reinstall vs2022, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Note that your images are actually of two different views, in the first you are viewing the actual folder structure, in the second you are viewing the solution.

Folder view shows you the actual files and folders of the "project/folder" you opened in VS, while solution explorer shows you an arbitrary organized view that can be however you like.

If you are opening a project/folder that you have created or downloaded externally, you will need to set up the solution yourself.
A project generated/cloned from VS directly should create a solution for you based on the folder structure.

The 0 solutions found suggests you are simply viewing the files in VS and haven't opened a SLN (solution) file.