# Solution Explorer of Visual Studio 2022 not updated after creating an ASP.NET Core Web API project inside the solution folder for mircoservices

Tags: asp.net, microservices, visual-studio-2022, ocelot

Hi Overflow Community,

I am new to .NET development and am having some trouble getting started right off the bat. I will list out the steps that I have done to be clear about what is going wrong.

I cannot seem to get the solution explorer to show the folder structure of the ASP.NET Core Web Api project I create inside the solution folder. I checked in the file system and all the project artifacts are created there, they just don't show up in the solution explorer.

## Steps

1. Create a Blank Solution
2. Create a Solution folder called Microservices

[image: Solution Structure]

3. Next I followed the steps shown in the screenshots to create an ASP.NET Core Web API project in the Microservices solution folder.

[image]

[image]

4. The expectation vs. reality with how the solution structure turned out after  did this

Expectation:

[image: The structure I want to have]

Reality:

[image: The empty structure]

I've tried every possible suggestion to make sure the solution explorer works and shows the structure I need to continue developing the API's but I can't get past this first step. If anyone could shed some light on why this happens that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I reproduced your steps and it works exactly as your expectation. here is my steps:  create sln file > add solution folder > right click folder and create api project.

Comment: I use console to create the sln file (eg: dotnet new sln -n MTIT)

Comment: I've seen this question asked multiple times now https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75114648/solution-explorer-in-visual-studio-2022 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74386006/why-my-latest-version-visual-studio-2022-does-not-contain-any-project-under-the.  It seems to be a weird random bug for Visual Studio.  I think the only way someone solved it was reinstalling visual studio, possibly multiple times.

Comment: Thank you @TimothyG. I will try that now and hopefully it works. I'm so glad SO has such a helpful community.

Answer (score 0):

So it seems you installed both versions 32-bit and 64-bit, and so the 32-bit was the first one added to the system's path.

Click on the windows key and start typing Edit the system variables and click on that option

GO TO LINK
https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/5962#issuecomment-780084535