# Visual Studio Missing Build Menu

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I'm facing a very weird problem. I've tried to install Visual Studio 2019 and 2022. For some unknown reason I can't see the files under solution explorer and also the Build menu is missing. I've tried to uninstall / modify the installation but none of them worked:

[image]

Any tips?

Comment: Your solution doesn't have any projects in it. Did you create your project with `dotnet new`?

Comment: I create using Visual Studio. There's a project, otherwise, how the Class1.cs was created?

Comment: This seems to be a reoccurring issue I've seen others ask multiple times: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75114648/solution-explorer-in-visual-studio-2022  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74386006/why-my-latest-version-visual-studio-2022-does-not-contain-any-project-under-the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76005258/solution-explorer-of-visual-studio-2022-not-updated-after-creating-an-asp-net-co - long story short, it seems only reinstalling has helped people with this (in one case a user had to reinstall it 3 times before it magically worked)...

Comment: Although it does look kind of weird how it says "Miscellaneous Files" in the top left.  For sanity, I guess check if the project is actually added to the  solution (you can look at the .sln file's underlying code to see if it is).

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to install multiple times visual studio 17.6.4 without success. I had to download an older version ([17.3](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2022/release-history#release-dates-and-build-numbers)) and it worked. I'm not sure what was the problem but that's how I managed to fix.